# Is it possible to change the email address linked to an account?

Tags: support, login, accounts

My account is (was) associated with a Gmail email address.
This Google account is one that I removed ages ago (Thursday, July 21 2016).
Now my Stack Overflow account has many points and badges. It's hard to start with a new account on a new email.

Is possible change my email address to another? I can authorize my Stack Overflow account with password and another Gmail account not exists.

Comment: If you go to [my logins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/me) you can add a new account there. Then you can *remove* your old one.

Comment: I have two accounts of Stack Exchange: sakujami@gmail.com and Stack Exchange; my Google account is without action "change password" , it means that I log by Google acount instead of Saku password; in this situation is secure delete sakujami account?

Comment: 2 accounts or 2 logins for a *single* account?

Comment: Also, sharing your email address publically is rarely the wisest choice. I got the prior data redacted, but it seems you *want* to share it?